# Nexus 7 and HTML5 Audio Loop

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio, nexus-7

I'm having trouble looping an audio tag on my Nexus 7 with Chrome.

```
<audio controls="" autoplay="" loop="">
    <source src="path/to/file.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    <source src="path/to/file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Looping works in Firefox.

Any ideas?

Comment: i have the same problem, on chrome: 28.0.1500.71, ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this issue occurs only on Linux machines - I'm using Debian Wheezy. I don't know why but I have switched to mp3 file and looping is working now.